# Next js build in vercel fails when with meta data. Why?

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering, vercel, next.js13

Here is layout.js. I have commented out the export const metadata, doing this makes the deployment to Vercel successful. Without commenting out the metadata, the deployment will fail.

```js
"use client";
import "./globals.css";
import { store } from "./store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

/*export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};*/

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <body
          style={{
            minHeight: "100vh",
            maxHeight: "fit-content",
            boxSizing: "border-box",
            backgroundColor: "#f2f5fd",
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </body>
      </Provider>
    </html>
  );
}
```

When I un-comment the metadata, the build deployment fails with the following errors.

```js
Failed to compile.
14:35:07.115

14:35:07.115
./app/layout.js
14:35:07.115
ReactServerComponentsError:
14:35:07.115

14:35:07.115
You are attempting to export "metadata" from a component marked with "use client", which is disallowed. Either remove the export, or the "use client" directive. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive
14:35:07.115

14:35:07.115
   ,-[/vercel/path0/app/layout.js:3:1]
14:35:07.115
3 | import { store } from "./store/store";
14:35:07.115
4 | import { Provider } from "react-redux";
14:35:07.115
5 | 
14:35:07.115
6 | export const metadata = {
14:35:07.116
   :              ^^^^^^^^
14:35:07.116
7 |   title: "Create Next App",
14:35:07.116
8 |   description: "Generated by create next app",
14:35:07.116
9 | };
14:35:07.116
   `----
14:35:07.116

14:35:07.116
File path:
14:35:07.116
  ./app/layout.js
14:35:07.116

14:35:07.116

14:35:07.116
> Build failed because of webpack errors
14:35:07.147
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
14:35:07.372
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Why does having the metadata cause the errors and what's the solution?

Answer (score 4):

After `<HTML>` starting tag on Layout I added `Head` tag to fix this problem!

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name='description' content='Description' />
      </head>
      <body className={`${inter.className} max-w-[1580px] mx-auto`}>
        
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Next.js, the "use client" directive is used when exporting data directly from the component to perform server-side rendering (SSR). When you use "use client," the component is intended to execute code only on the client-side. It means that you should not export any variables or data from a component marked with "use client" because it would cause issues with server-side rendering.

The error message is notifying you about this violation, suggesting two possible solutions:

1. Remove the export of "metadata" from the component.
2. Remove the "use client" directive if you need to export data from the component.

By following either of these solutions, you ensure that the component adheres to Next.js' guidelines for server-side rendering and exporting data, resolving the ReactServerComponentsError.

Comment: Does that mean I cannot change title or meta if I use any kind of hook ?

Answer (score 0):

[from here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-2)

> The new Metadata API allows you to define metadata (e.g. meta and link
> tags inside your HTML head element) with an explicit metadata
> configuration in any layout or page that is a Server Component.

Metadata works only in server components

Comment: Without the 'use client' in the page to make it a client component, there's going to be an Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: (0 , _react.createContext) is not a function

Comment: `Provider` works only on client side. that is why it has to be client component. you can define metadata in `pages.tsx` fserver iles

Answer (score -1):

> The root layout is a Server Component by default and can not be set to a Client Component.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

That means `app/layout.tsx` (or `app/layout.jsx`) has to be a Server Component.

Since `app` router is still not considered as stable (even though the core API is marked as stable in Next.js 13.4), there could still be "hacky" ways to bypass this issue. But those might not work in the long run. Hence, it's better to use what Next.js itself recommends.

So you need to remove the `"use client";` line from your Root Layout.

---

On a side note, you can move `<Provider>` component to below the `<body>`, like:

```
<html lang="en">
    <body
        style={{
        minHeight: "100vh",
        maxHeight: "fit-content",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        backgroundColor: "#f2f5fd",
    }}>
        <Provider store={store}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    </body>
</html>
```

> You should render providers as deep as possible in the tree
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers